Domain and port mapping doesn't work on Google Compute Engine with Docker and Nginx
First of all, I want to point out, that I am deploying my app with a non-recommended way.
Google suggested deploying a single container through GUI:

However Im doing it in a different way:
I git pull my project and then launch it with docker-compose and enable 7 containers with nginx, php, postfix, redis, db and some other stuff.

VM instance firewall allows http and https. And I can connect to host IP via http.
However, it seems it doesn't correctly pass domain to nginx, and I cant connect via domain name.
DNS is added correctly and domain name points to my VM, but after that it goes into timeout.
part of my docker-compose.yml:
  nginx-custom:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - php-fpm-custom
      - phpmyadmin
    image: nginx-custom:latest
    container_name: nginx-custom
    links:
      - phpmyadmin:phpmyadmin
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx/
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID}
        SITE_DOMAIN: ${SITE_DOMAIN}
        DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
        DB_ADMIN_WEBPATH: ${DB_ADMIN_WEBPATH}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - .:/var/www/site
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    expose:
      - '80'
      - '443'
    networks:
      - app-network

And default.conf for nginx:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        return 403;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name <SITE_DOMAIN added here via sed>;

    root /var/www/site/web;
    index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm-custom:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
}

What confuses me in the docs:

You can't map a VM instance's ports to the container's ports (Docker's
-p option). To enable access to your containers, see Publishing container ports.

I think this is the reason, but Im not sure, how to fix it, considering Im deploying with docker-compose. Because locally project works well and I can map a site.test on my local machine.

However, it seems it doesn't correctly pass domain to nginx, and I cant connect via domain name. Do you really mean like HTTPS does not work? (But how is it supposed to work when your nginx is not configured for that at all?) DNS is added correctly and domain name points to my VM And how exactly did you confirm that on the client?

@TomYan I mean both 80 and 443 (my 443 conf is almost the same as 80, except for ssl lines, i didnt post it here, cause 80 also doesnt work) just timeout when accessed via domain name.
But when I use PING domain.name from localhost it leads to my server IP.
Anyway, I think I fixed it, but I have another problem with OOM now, once I fix OOM and verify that my fix is working, I'll post the answer.

Well, it turned out I used an IP of my other server, not that one. Stupid mistake, that drained some time.
However I did experiment with configs while trying to figure it out, and also switched my configuration to use network_mode: "host"

Google Compute Engine doesn't support port mapping like docker's -p option (docker run -p command to map the container port to a host port).
As per the official GCP Document on Publishing container ports:

Container ports have a one-to-one mapping to the host VM ports. For example, a container port 80 maps to the host VM port 80. Compute Engine does not support the port publishing (-p) flag, and you do not have to specify it for the mapping to work.

Alternative-1:
You can use an App Engine flexible environment with a custom runtime instead. It is more suitable for running containers on GCE.
Alternative-2:
Try using a load balancer, which provides a stable, public IP address that doesn't change if you restart your VM also. It routes traffic from your domain to your container within the Docker-Compose network. In your DNS settings, make sure your domain name is pointing to the external IP address of your load balancer.
Also refer to the similar Github issue for more details.

It's really just talking about creating a VM with the gcloud CLI/API (create-with-container, as seen in the page you linked), which is basically some automation offered by Google that allows you to create a single-container VM (with host networking for the container) conveniently. It's not really that you can't open multiple ports on a Google VM, it's just that the API allows you to start only a single container. (I don't know about how exactly the firewall tag works, but I'm pretty sure there is a way to expose as many ports as you want in the firewall setting.) FWIW, it's still IaaS.

To state the obvious, the OP used / ran docker compose "directly" through SSH.
